# cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'String'

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm running into a situation where I want to extend a simple class by making it adopt the CustomStringConvertible protocol. However, when I do what the API directs me to do, the compiler hits me with a slew of errors.

Here's the part of the code that works...

```
struct Dog<String> {
    typealias Element = String
    var dogName: String
}

extension Dog: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    init(arrayLiteral: Element...) {
        let startIndex = arrayLiteral.startIndex
        let stringName = arrayLiteral[startIndex]
        self.init(dogName: stringName)
    } //end of init(arrayLiteral: Element...) for extension Domino
}


var d: Dog = ["Roofus", "Tony", "Rover"]
print("The dog's name is \(d.dogName)")
var d2: Dog = [1]
print("The dog's name is \(d2.dogName)")
var d3: Dog = [true]
print("The dog's name is \(d3.dogName)")
```

Everything above compiles just fine, and the print statements turn out what you would expect. However, when I add the `CustomStringConvertible` extension, like so...

```
extension Dog: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        get {
            return "testing with a constant string"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
error: type 'Dog<String>' does not conform to protocol 'CustomStringConvertible'
extension Dog: CustomStringConvertible {
^
Swift.CustomStringConvertible:67:16: note: protocol requires property 'description' with type 'String'; do you want to add a stub?
    public var description: String { get }
               ^
.../temp.swift:23:9: note: candidate has non-matching type 'String'
    var description: String {
        ^
.../temp.swift:25:20: error: cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'String'
            return "testing with a constant string"
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                    as! String
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Please shed some light on why I am getting the following response from the compiler: `cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'String'`.

**Edit**

Note: I get similar compiler feedback when I change the raw String expression to be an actual String value. That is, the following...

```
extension Dog: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        get {
            let s: String = "testing with a constant string"
            return s
        }
    }
}
```

... merely changes the feedback which says...

```
.../temp.swift:25:20: error: cannot convert return expression of type 'String' 
to return type 'String'
            return "testing with a constant string"
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                    as! String
```

to

```
.../temp.swift:25:20: error: cannot convert value of type 'String' 
to specified type 'String'
            return "testing with a constant string"
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                    as! String
```

**Edit**

Changed the title of this question to better reflect what my real conundrum was to begin with.

Comment: `Dog`'s `String` generic parameter is shadowing Swift's `String` type.  Either rename `String` to something else (which I'd recommend), or use `Swift.String` whenever you need to refer to Swift's `String` type.

Comment: Why is the dog name generic? o.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the comments of [NobodyNada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3476191/nobodynada) and [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander), I figured it out.

For some reason, I was thinking I had to make the generic type for `Dog` be equal to the type for the `typealias` that `Element` is assigned to... and I was thinking I had to do this to get `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` to work for the `Dog` type.

...well, I don't.

In fact, one does not even need generics to make `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` work (although I'm sure there are handy ways to meld generics and the `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` protocol).

That said, my revised code works properly. Specifically,

```
struct Dog {
    typealias Element = String
    var dogName: String
}

extension Dog: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    init(arrayLiteral: Element...) {
        let startIndex = arrayLiteral.startIndex
        let stringName = arrayLiteral[startIndex]
        self.init(dogName: stringName)
    } //end of init(arrayLiteral: Element...) for extension Dog
}


var d: Dog = ["Roofus", "Tony", "Rover"]
print("The dog's name is \(d.dogName)")
var d2: Dog = ["1"]
print("The dog's name is \(d2.dogName)")
var d3: Dog = ["true"]
print("The dog's name is \(d3.dogName)")

extension Dog: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        let s: String = "testing with a constant string"
        return s
    }
}

var d4: Dog = ["x"]
print("\(d4)")
```

has output of:

```
The dog's name is Roofus
The dog's name is 1
The dog's name is true
testing with a constant string
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Comment: It seems Swift should really give better compiler warning/error messages about these things. Can it not detect that I've used a Swift standard lib type's name for my generic type? Will Swift 4 detect this?